# Set the major version number of a managed package

Tags: managed-package, versioning

Can I set the version of managed package to a desired version number?

I've a managed package whose version number is something like 1.x. I would like to set the version number to 2.0 for the next release as it has been changed a lot.

### It it possible to set the major version number of the package when publishing it.

### EDIT:

Both answers below are somewhat correct, I picked the one I thought as best as the answer.

My confusion was, that once I released a package as a Managed-beta I can't change it's version, but it can be freely edited after I've made the beta into a managed release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the "Version Number" field displayed when you "Upload" the managed package can have its number manually changed from 1.x to 2.0. We are presently on 6.x for one of our managed packages.

(Note that if your managed package is subject to a Salesforce [Security Review](https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Security_Review), changing this number may prompt the significant expense of a re-review. But I guess that is only appropriate if the amount of change is large.)

Comment: Actually this only works if your latest upload is not a beta package.

Comment: @stvnhg Good point. We rarely use beta packages as they bring too many problems for on-going packages.

Comment: Have you got a source on that security re-review?

Comment: Hi @zaitsman No I don't; note this is a post from 2014. I understand that today it is at the security team's discretion so in theory at least is likely driven by the amount of change.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already created the package, there is no way to change it. You'll need to create a  new package, even though you don't include any new change and specify the major version you wish.

Salesforce uses the versioning numbers to define the *-meta.xml files and allow other packages or components to use an specific version of your package. There's nothing to do with publishing